# Edited form not getting saved in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've fixed almost everything, the form opens and I can make the edits but as soon as I make the edits and click on save, this shows up:

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong. I did the same thing for my edit profile page and it worked perfectly there so I don't understand why it's not working here.

views.py:

```
class EditComplaint(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
   model = Complaint
   fields = ('reportnumber', 'eventdate', 'event_type', 'device_problem', 'manufacturer', 
  'product_code', 'brand_name', 'exemption', 'patient_problem', 'event_text', 'document')  
   template_name = 'newcomplaint.html'
   def form_valid(self, request):
       complaint = request.user.complaint
       form = ComplaintForm(instance=complaint)
       if request.method == 'POST':
          form = ComplaintForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=complaint)
          if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
       context = {'form': form}
       return render(request, 'newcomplaint.html', context)

   def test_func(self):
       complain = self.get_object()

       if self.request.user == complain.user:
           return True
       raise Http404(_('This complain does not exist'))
```

urls.py:

```
path('Complaint/<int:pk>/edit/', accounts.views.EditComplaint.as_view(), 
name='Complaint')
```

What seems to be wrong? I think I need to change something in my views because everything else seems to work well so I'm not including anything else. But i don't understand what needs to be changed

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report 
            number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event 
            type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 
           'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 
            130px;width:760px'}),
            'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter 
            Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter 
            Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter 
            Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter 
            Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 
           'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       }
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = 
   True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= 
   False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, 
   blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, 
   blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, 
   blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, 
   blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, 
   blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, 
   null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

`form_valid` has as second parameter the `form` that has been validated, not the request. You can access the request with `self.request`.

But you do not need to handle this yourself: the `UpdateView` logic has already logic in place to create and validate a POST request. It will run `form_valid` only if the form is valid, and by default save the form and redirect to the success url:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class EditComplaint(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Complaint
    form_class = ComplaintForm
    success_url = 'url-to-redirect-to'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )
```

> I did the same thing for my edit profile page and it worked perfectly.

Class-based views normally implement most of the codeflow, so it is usually only a matter of specifying some items like the `form_class`, `success_url`, etc. Usually, if you need to write large blocks of logic it means you implement the logic that is already there in place, or the view is complicated and thus should be implemented by a function-based view, or another class-based view.

When the success url depends on the object, you can override `get_success_url`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse

class EditComplaint(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Complaint
    form_class = ComplaintForm

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('Complaint', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

You can automatically set the user by omitting the `user` field in the form, and set the `user` with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse

class EditComplaint(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Complaint
    form_class = ComplaintForm

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('Complaint', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: What do I put in the success url if like I want it to redirect to itself after editing it?

Comment: If you have the name of the view, you can work with [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy): `reverse_lazy('name-of-view')`

Comment: `success_url = reverse_lazy('Complaint')`  this is what I put but it still does not recognize, Sorry, I'm a beginner at django and don't know how reverse_lazy and redirect works

Comment: But it should be the *name* of the view, can you share the `urls.py` by editing your question...

Comment: added the url pattern

Comment: @IshaJagadi: in that case the `success_url` should be determined by the `get_success_url` method.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452333/what-do-i-put-in-the-success-url-in-my-django-view-right-now-this-isnt-saving)   Can you please check this out once and see what is going wrong

Comment: @IshaJagadi: see updated answer... Furthermore please do *not* use the `UserPassesTestMixin`, this will perform extra queries on the database. By filtering the `QuerYSet` that should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it still shows page not found and the new edits are not changing in the my-history page either. They do get changed in the admin panel though.

Comment: @IshaJagadi: did you fully modify your view to the last one described in the answer, so *without* the `UserPassesTestMixin`, and *with* the `get_success_url` that has a `kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}`?

Comment: yes, i did. but i got tired of it failing again and again so now instead it gets redirected to the my-history page. this works, but the new problem now is that the complaints i'm editted do get the changes saved but also changes the user to null so now on the myhistory page I can't see those complaints

Comment: @IshaJagadi: edit the question with the details of the *form*.

Comment: Added the forms as well as the models.py

Comment: @IshaJagadi: your form has `'__all__` as fields, so that means that the user field is part of the Form and thus the form expects that the request will contain a reference to the user.

Comment: ok... but it was working well while accepting new complaints, what should I do here?

Comment: @ishaJagadi: use a form *without* the `user`, and set the user in the `form_valid` method.