# User field is getting changed to Null everytime I update the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Everytime I select a complaint and edit it, the user field in the admin panel changes to Null "----"
Can someone please give me a solution for this. Because of this whenever I go back to the my-history page I can't see the edited complaints

views.py:

```
class EditComplaint(UpdateView):
   model = Complaint
   form_class = ComplaintForm
   template_name = 'newcomplaint.html'
   success_url = '/My-History/'
   def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
           user=self.request.user
       )

   def form_valid(self, form):
      if form.is_valid():
         form.instance.author = self.request.user
      return super().form_valid(form)       

   def test_func(self):
       complain = self.get_object()

       if self.request.user == complain.user:
           return True
       raise Http404(_('This complain does not exist'))
```

models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
           'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       }
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `form_valid` method of `UpdateView` in your `view` class and explicitly set the logged-in user as the user for your `form`.

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It's still not working, having the same problem

Comment: are you sure you're looking at the same form? could you just create a new form and try editing it.

Comment: Can you please show how. I'm like super confused right now and don't understand what to do. What if I change the form and then the accepting complaints page changes too

Comment: i am asking you to use your UI to create a new form and then go the edit url and try and see if the changes work or not.

Comment: Also, please try to use something like `breakpoint` or `print` inside the `form_valid` to see if it is getting called and see what who the user  is inside `form` or for the `request`, etc.

Comment: Ok, I did this and the changes are showing in the admin panel but the only issue is the user field. I also added a print statement in the form_valid to check if it's getting called and yeah it is getting called as well

Comment: are you sure you're checking for the form that you edited?

Comment: this could also happen in case your the statement `form.is_valid()` return `False`. Could you please verify that as well.

Comment: yeah, i used this form to accept new complaints and now I'm using the same form to edit them as well. I added a new complaint and tried editing it but does not work

Comment: I added the print statement inside the if form.is_valid() and it is getting printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235098/discussion-between-abhyudai-and-isha-jagadi).